# Почему в массив не пушится один 0?

Tags: javascript

Решаю задачки на code wars. Просят переместить все `0` в конец массива, сохраняя порядок всех остальных элементов. Допустим есть массив:

```
[1,2,0,1,0,1,0,3,0,1]
```

Надо получить массив

```
[ 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
```

Я написал функцию, которая возвращает такой

```
[ 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0]
```

и поэтому не проходит тест. Вот код:

```
let moveZeros = function (arr) {
  // TODO: Program me
  let oldLength = arr.length;
  arr = arr.filter(element => element !== 0)
  for (let i = 0; i <= oldLength - arr.length; i++) arr.push(0);
  return arr;
}
```

Вопрос: куда делся один `0`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
i <= oldLength - arr.length;
```

вычисляется *перед каждой* итерацией.